# Angular pipe changes original object

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have a pipe to filter an Array by a daterange from userinput, the filter is working fine when making the array smaller but on increasing the daterange afterwards, the pipe is working with the small array again which was the result of the filter before.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dateinrangePipe'
})

export class DateInRangePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(obj: any[], from: Date, to: Date): any[] {
        if (obj && from && to) {
            console.log('before:');
            obj.forEach(data => {
                console.log(data.name);
                data.series = data.series.filter((item: any) => {
                    return this.inRange(item.name, from, to);
                });
            });
        }
        console.log(obj);
        return [...obj];
    }

    inRange(date: Date, from: Date, to: Date): boolean {
        return date.getTime() >= from.getTime() &&
            date.getTime() <= to.getTime() ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Edit:

Pipe is used for the data of a ngx-chart

```
 <ngx-charts-line-chart
        ...
        [results]="multi | dateinrangePipe: from: to"
        ...>
 </ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

Comment: can you show usage off this pipe for example in ngFor?

Comment: You are overwriting the property `series` of each object

Comment: You shouldn't use a pipe in the first pace to do that: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe. But even if you do it in your component, you should not modify the objects as you're doing. You should create a filtered copy instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a copy of the input data, but this is pointless, as you assign a value to `data.series` before. As `data` is a reference, you modify `obj`.

Comment: Even though obj is passed with 'call by value', data inside obj is a reference to the original object?

Comment: Thx. Inside the pipe I created a clone with `let objClone = obj.map((x: any) => Object.assign({}, x));` to break the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can add -

```
const strObj = JSON.stringfy(obj);

const copyObj = JSON.parse(strObj);
```

I think this is an easy solution because the spread operator and `Object.assign` not effect insides objects.